# trying to run app on device

Tags: android, android-studio, device

I am trying to run a simple app in my device I am using a GALAXY S5 but the app would never launch, in the Android Studio the log cat is just loading and loading like this:

```
-10 19:07:07.856    3006-3006/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger﹕ checkOverflow(576), More:false, Req:false Child:3
08-10 19:07:08.836    3006-3006/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 13   -121 -13 16 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x0 level=0
08-10 19:07:09.306     912-6264/? D/SSRMv2:SIOP﹕ SIOP:: AP = 280, PST = 287,  Delta = -1
08-10 19:07:09.316     912-6264/? D/AmoledAdjustTimer﹕ prevTemp = 264,  currTemp = 264, prevStep = 4, currStep = 4
08-10 19:07:09.866    3006-3006/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
08-10 19:07:09.866    3006-3006/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
08-10 19:07:09.886    3006-3006/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger﹕ checkOverflow(576), More:false, Req:false Child:3
08-10 19:07:09.916     912-3520/? D/BatteryService﹕ level:100, scale:100,  status:5, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4372, temperature: 263, technology:  Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false,  icon:17303678, invalid charger:0, online:6, current avg:1000, charge type:0,  power sharing:false
```

This is the console :

```
Installing com.example.juano.stiktag
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.juano.stiktag"
```

pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.juano.stiktag
Success

```
Launching application:com.example.juano.stiktag/com.example.juano.stiktag.LoginActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.example.juano.stiktag/com.example.juano.stiktag.LoginActivity" -a   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat= [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.juano.stiktag/.LoginActivity  }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {  act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]  flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.juano.stiktag/.LoginActivity } from null  (pid=13739, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10247
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at  android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2367)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)
```

Sometimes it finish but still the app never launch, however in the virtual device works, I tried to follow all the steps on the android studio website enable usb debugger, please any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: can u see your device in studio?

Comment: Yes no problem, even when I go to developer options -> select debug app , I can see the app i want to install in the device

Comment: while launching the app does it shows the available devices as to where you want to launch your app?

Comment: yes it says samsung SM-G900F android 4.4.2

Comment: check for any error messages in your console (not logcat).It could be regarding the memory of device.And try using any other device and see if the prob still persists.

Comment: I added the console report on the post, can you give it a look?

Comment: have u added all the necessary permissions in your manifest 
(for eg:- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>) if you are using internet.?.This is something regarding the permissions.or have u defined a launcher activity.Maybe you can post your xml here.

Comment: I don't know anything about that, I don't need internet permissions though is just a simple login screen

Comment: just paste your manifest file and let me see

Comment: It's probably because you've declared the same activity twice in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem by setting the activity as a default launcher